# Route Configuration in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

The current Route Config for me is this, which I think is the default one

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I write

```
www.mypage.com  
www.mypage.com/home
```

I get the same page

How Can I make it so that they are two individual pages

```
www.mypage.com
```

is the homepage, and

```
www.mypage.com/home
```

is another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.mypage.com can be handler by a root controller and all the other routes will be handled by the default route.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Root",
        url: "",
        defaults: new {controller = "Root", action = "Index"}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

the explicit defaults allow for the behavior you are currently seeing.

You will still need to create a controller to handle your root site calls

```
public class RootController : Controller {    
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to create the related View for your controller.

Comment: Great! It worked, but where do I put the view for www.mypage.com now?

Comment: I may need to edit my answer. You will still need to create a default controller for your root url

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new controller. you can use the same home controller. In Home Controller, create 2 actions - Default and Index. In the routeconfig, use -

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RootDef",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );      
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```